# Pass ssl cert information from nginx to flask

Tags: python, ssl, nginx, uwsgi

I'm setting up a REST API to be used by clients my company controls. I've built it on Flask-restless and am serving it with uWSGI and nginx.

For authenticating clients and for security we use mutual SSL certificates. So the communication channel is secure and the client presents a certificate to authenticate.

Although nginx does validate the certs I need to access the certificate information from within the Flask app so i can grant access only to some endpoints and/or select data.

The question is how can i pass the certificate info to the Flask app.

Comment: My bet is that you can't do that directly. You could put this information it in the http request headers but I'm pretty sure it's not secure. The way to authenticate users is usually using their sessions. Then you can put whatever you want in the session to help yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it!

you just export `uwsgi_param YOUR_NAME_HERE $variable;` in the nginx conf file.

for my purposes it looks like this

```
uwsgi_param CLIENT_VERIFY $ssl_client_verify;
uwsgi_param CLIENT_CERT $ssl_client_s_dn;
```

Comment: Thank you! This answer is still relevant today. There are also plenty of other options http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables to suit everyone's needs.

Comment: @BojanP. That's quite a large piece missing from the answer. Thanks for sharing.