# Access SSL certificate information from within the Flask application

Tags: python, ssl, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm developing a small application for m copany. 
 I've built it with Flask and am serving it with Gunicorn and nginx as a reverse proxy.
For authenticating employees that log in to this application, we use client-side SSL certificates.

Although nginx does validate the certs I need to access the certificate information from within the Flask app so i can enter the email adresses into a dtabase.

How can I pass the certificate info to the Flask app?

This Question is very similiar to 
[Pass ssl cert information from nginx to flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653696/pass-ssl-cert-information-from-nginx-to-flask)

But the OP uses uWSGI and I don't really understand the accepted answer…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your client certificate through the proxy header. Add this line on your Nginx server configurations:

```
proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_escaped_cert;
```

This configuration will forward client certificate (urlencoded) through X-SSL-CERT header. Then, your Flask app can access it by getting this header.

Comment: May be worth adding, the header can then be grabbed in flask with `request.headers.get('X-SSL-CERT')`.  Also the [available variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables) which can be passed from nginx.